# default tab not showing content while load the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

while load the page, one tab should show its content by default on page load, anyone tell me modification of JS

JS:

```
 var $tabs = $('.tabs > div'), _currhash, $currTab;`function showTab() {
   if($currTab.length>0) {  
     $tabs.removeClass('active');
     $currTab.addClass('active');
   }
}`/* find the panels and 'unlink' the id to prevent page jump */
$tabs.each(function() {
   var _id = $(this).attr('id');
   $(this).attr('id',_id+'_tab');
   /* eg we have given the tab an id of 'tab1_tab' */
});`/* set up an anchor 'watch' for the panels */
function anchorWatch() {`if(document.location.hash.length>0) {
    /* only run if 'hash' has changed */
    if(_currhash!==document.location.hash) {
       _currhash = document.location.hash;`/* we only want to match the 'unlinked' id's */
       $currTab = $(_currhash+'_tab');
       showTab();
   }
  }
} ` setInterval(anchorWatch,300);
```

JSfiddle not working so check html and css code here - [tabs](http://ssconsultancyservices.com/myhtml.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hiding all tabs using css so you will have to add active class on the first tab to make it visible.

your css which is causing this.

```
 .tabs > div { display:none;}
 .tabs > div.active { display:block;}
```

Code to set the active class on first tab.

```
$tabs.first().addClass("active");
```

```js
  var $tabs = $('.tabs > div'), _currhash, $currTab;

   $tabs.first().addClass("active");
    
    function showTab() {
       if($currTab.length>0) {  
         $tabs.removeClass('active');
         $currTab.addClass('active');
       }
    }
    /* find the panels and 'unlink' the id to prevent page jump */
    $tabs.each(function() {
       var _id = $(this).attr('id');
       $(this).attr('id',_id+'_tab');
       /* eg we have given the tab an id of 'tab1_tab' */
    });

    /* set up an anchor 'watch' for the panels */
    function anchorWatch() {
      if(document.location.hash.length>0) {
        /* only run if 'hash' has changed */
        if(_currhash!==document.location.hash) {
           _currhash = document.location.hash;
           /* we only want to match the 'unlinked' id's */
           $currTab = $(_currhash+'_tab');
           showTab();
       }
      }
    } 
    setInterval(anchorWatch,300);
```

```css
 .tabs > div { display:none;}
 .tabs > div.active { display:block;}
    
 a { display:inline-block; padding:0.5em;}
.tabs > div { padding:1em; border:2px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div>
<a href="#tab1">link to tab 1</a>
</div>

  <!-- links -->
  <a href="#tab1">Domain Names</a>
  <a href="#tab2">SSL Certificates</a>
  <a href="#tab3">Hosted Email</a>
  <a href="#tab4">Web Security</a>
  <a href="#tab5">Portfolio</a>

  <!-- content -->
  <div class="tabs">
    <div id="tab1"> <h1 style="
    text-align: center;
">Domain Names</h1></h1>
        <h3 style="
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -10px;
    color: #0d0d0d;
">Every domain extension you will ever need...and more.</h3>
  <p>We gives you access to the largest selection of domain names available on the market through a single platform. All generic, specialty and country-code extensions at competitive prices plus hundreds of brand new top-level domains including an available inventory of over 17 million premium domains.</p> </div>
    <div id="tab2"> Tab Two content </div>
    <div id="tab3"> 
      Tab Three content with a 
    </div>
    <div id="tab4"> Tab Four content </div>
 <div id="tab5"> 
<p>Currently associated with  Inc – one of world’s largest & oldest WebRegistrar. in IT from QUT; Australia & is based in Mumbai (India).</p>
 </div>
  </div>
 
 
</body>
```